# Recreate hist() binning in ggplot2 with geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

*(if you are only interested in the problem, then go to **"What if in short?"**)*

**What kind of stupid question?**

I'm doing work and before that I built all graphics with `ggplot2` and I don't want to change the style.

And now I need a histogram, but it does not suit me with `ggplot2`.

**What do I mean?**

I took the width of the column from `hist()`, so there will be the same number of them
(which can be seen from the graphs),
but in `hist()` and as I want,
the bars do NOT cross the important/magic number 0.0012,
and in `geom_histogram` intersects.

**What if in short?**

How to "shift" histogram bars with `ggplot2` so that they do not cross a certain number (0.0012)?
Or, how to make a histogram shorter with "data" from `hist()` and design with `ggplot2`?

**Here is my code:**

```
# check bin width
standard_hist <- hist(my_vector, plot = F)
bw <- standard_hist$breaks[2] - standard_hist$breaks[1]
  
# create hist with ggplot and bw from standard hist
gghist <- ggplot(mapping = aes(my_vector)) +
    geom_histogram(
      binwidth = bw,
      color = "black",
      fill = "white"
    )
```

and result:

1. my hist

[image: my hist]

2. standard hist

[image: standard hist]

**FIX:**

from joran --- instead of `geom_histogram()` use `stat_bin()` as here:

```
stat_bin(geom = 'bar',breaks = <breaks vector from hist() output>)
```

**My data:**

```
my_vector <- (0.001201367, 0.001199250, 0.001198337, 0.001199200, 0.001199353, 0.001198439, 0.001202447, 0.001205639, 0.001207056, 0.001209714, 0.001204478, 0.001200064, 0.001199386, 0.001199976, 0.001200569, 0.001204738, 0.001208508, 0.001201491, 0.001200995, 0.001199861, 0.001200242, 0.001196367, 0.001200365, 0.001201807, 0.001194364, 0.001197196, 0.001192705, 0.001196178, 0.001192991, 0.001189777, 0.001194227, 0.001197158, 0.001204336, 0.001201081, 0.001201100, 0.001204755, 0.001198810, 0.001202090, 0.001194370, 0.001188529, 0.001191450, 0.001193616, 0.001195733, 0.001198886, 0.001201353, 0.001206878, 0.001201262, 0.001194806, 0.001196192, 0.001193215, 0.001195030, 0.001198202, 0.001184351, 0.001191890, 0.001192882, 0.001194621, 0.001203256, 0.001204150, 0.001197425, 0.001198002, 0.001196185, 0.001194915, 0.001198281, 0.001201858, 0.001195349, 0.001196401, 0.001205476, 0.001201740, 0.001197276, 0.001189442, 0.001192760, 0.001196846, 0.001201342, 0.001204854, 0.001202979, 0.001203136, 0.001199926, 0.001197398, 0.001199905, 0.001199252, 0.001198486, 0.001197114, 0.001196829, 0.001200228, 0.001199666, 0.001194918, 0.001204005, 0.001201363, 0.001204183, 0.001205889, 0.001204553, 0.001202369, 0.001203922, 0.001197001, 0.001200020, 0.001202672, 0.001201746, 0.001203532, 0.001198699, 0.001200975, 0.001202635, 0.001203121, 0.001190614, 0.001199029, 0.001200372, 0.001193731, 0.001193428, 0.001200259, 0.001195203, 0.001194854, 0.001193173, 0.001198266, 0.001195362, 0.001195252, 0.001201008, 0.001199291, 0.001196653, 0.001200357, 0.001201623, 0.001207463, 0.001199381, 0.001198047, 0.001196305, 0.001200419, 0.001208689, 0.001197434, 0.001193885, 0.001198708, 0.001204741, 0.001204281, 0.001193663, 0.001200234, 0.001203809, 0.001199003, 0.001195127, 0.001192189, 0.001187610, 0.001191390, 0.001200602, 0.001197817, 0.001202045, 0.001203998, 0.001205508, 0.001201051, 0.001202057, 0.001208911, 0.001203928, 0.001202267, 0.001201434, 0.001202647, 0.001210024, 0.001210509, 0.001207881, 0.001206928, 0.001206128, 0.001203866, 0.001202204, 0.001204511, 0.001202310, 0.001197504, 0.001199019, 0.001200713, 0.001204197, 0.001204649, 0.001207965, 0.001201847, 0.001200585, 0.001203446, 0.001195972, 0.001202405, 0.001197182, 0.001191603, 0.001197663, 0.001202259, 0.001201008, 0.001200354, 0.001198090, 0.001193479, 0.001202457, 0.001201156, 0.001196038, 0.001201092, 0.001205488, 0.001212173, 0.001203497, 0.001208846, 0.001198349, 0.001200047, 0.001200799, 0.001206939, 0.001207142, 0.001201970, 0.001202742, 0.001204795, 0.001198463, 0.001201559, 0.001201344, 0.001206085, 0.001205526, 0.001197508)
```

Comment: It is good practice to include some sample data in your question, to reduce ambiguity and to save each potential answerer from needing to reverse engineer their own.

Comment: For instance, would it be adequate for us all to use `set.seed(42); my_vector <- rnorm(200, 0.0012, 0.000003))`? I'm not sure that demonstrates the binning effect you are looking to recreate in ggplot2.

Comment: I don't know what the theoretical distribution of "A" is, but I am now looking for a way to save my vector so that others can easily create it themselves. If you happen to know, please let me know.

Comment: I believe `stat_bin()` accepts an explicit `breaks` argument, so you could do `stat_bin(geom = 'hist',breaks = <breaks vector from hist() output>)`, perhaps?

Comment: Gah, I think that should be `geom = 'bar'` in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data, I believe this does what you want:

```
h <- hist(my_vector)

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = my_vector),aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_bin(geom = 'bar',breaks = h$breaks)
```